# Property 'origin' does not exist on type '{} In Expo and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I got error when I tried push notifications in expo react native.
I am using TypeScript

this is my code: in data and origin error appear: "Property 'origin' does not exist on type '{}'." also for data "Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'. what the problem is? I give the data " as any" but still not working.
"

```
<Text>Origin: {(this.state.notification.origin)}</Text>
          <Text>Data: {JSON.stringify(this.state.notification.data)}</Text>
```

Comment: This error clearly 'shows that notification' object doesn't have 'origin' or 'data' properties. Please make sure that this object is populated with said properties and remove any bug in case any...

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly provide a type for the value of notification, typescript will infer the type as `{}` which is not what you want.

```
const state = {
  notification: {},
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(state.notification.data)). // Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.
console.log(state.notification.origin) // Property 'origin' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

If you provide a type for notification, typescript will be expecting the properties on the type (`origin` and `data`), so will not cause an error when you try to access them.

```
type TNotification = {
  origin?: string;
  data?: {
    [key: string]: any
  }
};

const state: {
  notification: TNotification;
} = {
  notification: {},
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(state.notification.data))
console.log(state.notification.origin)
```